# Uber Zap logger not printing caller information in the log statement

Tags: go, go-zap

I am trying to put the same message to console and the log files at the same time with custom encoder for config. In the process I want to display the caller information but the same is not being displayed even if I have used `caller` key as suggested in the documentation.

Below is the sample code for the same

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "time"

    "go.uber.org/zap"
    "go.uber.org/zap/zapcore"
    "gopkg.in/natefinch/lumberjack.v2"
)

var logLevelSeverity = map[zapcore.Level]string{
    zapcore.DebugLevel:  "DEBUG",
    zapcore.InfoLevel:   "INFO",
    zapcore.WarnLevel:   "WARNING",
    zapcore.ErrorLevel:  "ERROR",
    zapcore.DPanicLevel: "CRITICAL",
    zapcore.PanicLevel:  "ALERT",
    zapcore.FatalLevel:  "EMERGENCY",
}

func SyslogTimeEncoder(t time.Time, enc zapcore.PrimitiveArrayEncoder) {
    enc.AppendString(t.Format("Jan 01, 2006  15:04:05"))
}

func CustomEncodeLevel(level zapcore.Level, enc zapcore.PrimitiveArrayEncoder) {
    enc.AppendString(logLevelSeverity[level])
}

func CustomLevelFileEncoder(level zapcore.Level, enc zapcore.PrimitiveArrayEncoder) {
    enc.AppendString("[" + logLevelSeverity[level] + "]")
}

func main() {

    w := zapcore.AddSync(&lumberjack.Logger{
        Filename:   "temp1.log",
        MaxSize:    1024,
        MaxBackups: 20,
        MaxAge:     28,
        Compress:   true,
    })

    //Define config for the console output
    cfgConsole := zapcore.EncoderConfig{
        MessageKey:   "message",
        LevelKey:     "severity",
        EncodeLevel:  CustomEncodeLevel,
        TimeKey:      "time",
        EncodeTime:   SyslogTimeEncoder,
        CallerKey:    "caller",
        EncodeCaller: zapcore.FullCallerEncoder,
    }
    cfgFile := zapcore.EncoderConfig{
        MessageKey:   "message",
        LevelKey:     "severity",
        EncodeLevel:  CustomLevelFileEncoder,
        TimeKey:      "time",
        EncodeTime:   SyslogTimeEncoder,
        CallerKey:    "caller",
        EncodeCaller: zapcore.FullCallerEncoder,
    }

    consoleDebugging := zapcore.Lock(os.Stdout)
    //consoleError := zapcore.Lock(os.Stderr)
    core := zapcore.NewTee(
        zapcore.NewCore(zapcore.NewConsoleEncoder(cfgFile), w, zap.DebugLevel),
        zapcore.NewCore(zapcore.NewJSONEncoder(cfgConsole), consoleDebugging, zap.DebugLevel),
        //zapcore.NewCore(zapcore.NewJSONEncoder(zap.NewProductionEncoderConfig()), consoleError, zap.ErrorLevel),
    )
    //core := zapcore.NewCore(zapcore.NewConsoleEncoder(encConsole), w, zap.DebugLevel)
    wlogger := zap.New(core)
    wlogger.Debug("Sample debug for log file and console")
    wlogger.Warn("An warning message example")
    wlogger.Info("An info level message")
    coreFile := zapcore.NewCore(zapcore.NewConsoleEncoder(cfgFile), w, zap.DebugLevel)
    flogger := zap.New(coreFile)
    flogger.Debug("An exclusive message for file")
    //output
    //{"severity":"DEBUG","time":"Nov 11, 2018  20:24:11","message":"Sample debug for log file and console"}
    //{"severity":"WARNING","time":"Nov 11, 2018  20:24:11","message":"An warning message example"}
    //{"severity":"INFO","time":"Nov 11, 2018  20:24:11","message":"An info level message"}
}
```

Any thoughts why the caller information is not being displayed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

according to documentation https://godoc.org/go.uber.org/zap#AddCaller
you can do something like this on logger creation:

```
wlogger := zap.New(core, zap.AddCaller())
```

**update answer to comment**
also you can define your implementation of caller encode:

```
func MyCaller(caller zapcore.EntryCaller, enc zapcore.PrimitiveArrayEncoder) {
    enc.AppendString(filepath.Base(caller.FullPath()))
}
```

and pass it to *cfgConsole* and *cfgFile*

Comment: It work but how to just put filename instead `go-play/log.go:75` to `log.go:75`

Comment: you can define your implementation of CallerEncoder   

`func MyCaller(caller zapcore.EntryCaller, enc zapcore.PrimitiveArrayEncoder) {
 enc.AppendString(filepath.Base(caller.FullPath()))
}`

Answer (score 12):

[AddCallerSkip](https://godoc.org/go.uber.org/zap#AddCallerSkip) can help you skip caller's call stack depth.

```golang
// before
zap.New(core, zap.AddCaller())
// output: {"level":"panic","time":"2020-06-09T16:08:25.677+0800","line":"log/log.go:118","msg":"before")}

// add caller skip
zap.New(core, zap.AddCaller(), zap.AddCallerSkip(1))
// output: {"level":"panic","time":"2020-06-09T16:47:39.559+0800","line":"client/client.go:29","msg":"after"}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in whatever wrapper calls `Log()` itself? `AddCallerSkip` is global for the whole logger, but i'd like the option of calling Log directly or in a wrapper... I only want skip in the wrapper's call to Log, and not everyone else's call to log